# Set layout_gravity to center for custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, custom-component

I am creating a custom LinearLayout just to measure and properly resize it:

```
public class Frame extends LinearLayout
{
private int width;
private int height;
private Context context;

public Frame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int newwidth=MeasureSpec
                           .makeMeasureSpec(height*480/720,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(newwidth, heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

It works perfectly, but it obviously keeps its position on the place before the measure changed so it is not centered horizontally anymore. How can I override the settings in my custom LinearLayout to make it appear in the horizontal center?

This is how I call it in he xml file:

```
com.myproject.main.Frame 
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@id/button"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="480" >
```

Comment: *but it obviously keeps its position on the place before the measure changed* -  Can you be a little more clear about what is happening? Do you want to center horizontally this custom `LinearLayout`?

Comment: yes I want it to center it horizontally.
the layout, not its children.

Comment: Did you tried `android:layout_gravity="center"` for your custom view?

Comment: Aaaah, this helped. Silly me. I had it there and then it disappeared :) Thanks.